# SOLR Partial / Exact word Search term Highlighting

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am new to SOLR. I am getting the desired response that I want but I am not able to highlight the exact search term.

SOLR Version: `8.6.3`

**Query:** `/selectq=*sta*&df=title&start=0&rows=2&mm=100&defType=edismax&fl=title&hl.method=unified&pf3=title^3&ps3=1&pf2=title^3&ps2=1&qf=title&hl=on&hl.q=*sta*`

**Existing:**

**Search Term:** `sta`

```
"docs": [
            {
                "title": "Stanford University",
            },
            {
                "title": "Texas State University",
            }
        ]
    },
    "highlighting": {
        "9781743310": {
            "title": [
                "<em>Stanford</em> University"
            ]
        },
        "9781909421": {
            "title": [
                "Texas <em>State</em> University"
            ]
        }
```

**Expected:**

**Search Term:** `sta`

```
"docs": [
            {
                "title": "Stanford University",
            },
            {
                "title": "Texas State University",
            }
        ]
    },
    "highlighting": {
        "9781743310": {
            "title": [
                "<em>Sta</em>stanford University"
            ]
        },
        "9781909421": {
            "title": [
                "Texas <em>Sta</em>te University"
            ]
        }
```

Comment: I think you are searching for wildcard search and you have field type as String...hence it is happening...

Comment: Hey @AbhijitBashetti Without the wildcard "*" it is not highlighting the term.

`Example search Term: Dalsford State Un
<em>Dalsford</em> <em>State</em> University`

`Example search Term: Dalsford State Un*
<em>Dalsford</em> <em>State</em> <em>University</em>`

Comment: Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507065/how-can-i-highlight-only-the-search-term-in-apache-solr